# Can I build an if expression ouside the if statement in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to build an if expression outside the if statement itself? Can I concatenate multiple conditions outside the statement and then test them in another if statement?

For example

```
$var= '$varCars==5 && varBikes == '.$totalBikes;

if(isset($trucks){
  $var= $var.' && varTrucks=='.$totalTrucks';
}
if($var){
  run some code
}
```

This was easy in VBScript!!

Harj

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
$intA = 1;
$intB = 2;

// Returns boolean
$bool = ($intA === 1 && $intB === 2);
if($bool) echo "Yes, it is true<br>";

// if / else
$statement = ($intA === 1) ? 2 : 1;
if($statement === 2) echo "Yep, it is true.<br>";

// if / elseif / else
$statement = ($intA === 2) ? 2 : (($intB === 2) ? 2 : 1);
if($statement === 2) echo "Yep, intA is not equal to 2 but intB is, it is true.<br>";

// if / else concatenate in echo
echo "Hello ".(($intA === 2) ? "John" : "Jane")." do you want to grab some coffee?<br>";
```